# Github API: Retrieve all commits for all branches for a repo

Tags: github-api

According to the V2 documentation, you can list all commits for a branch with:

```
commits/list/:user_id/:repository/:branch
```

I am not seeing the same functionality in the V3 documentation.

I would like to collect all branches using something like:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/branches
```

And then iterate through them, pulling all commits for each. Alternatively, if there's a way to pull all commits for all branches for a repo directly, that would work just as well if not better. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I tried passing the branch :sha as a param as follows:

```
params = {:page => 1, :per_page => 100, :sha => b}
```

The problem is that when i do this, it doesn't page the results properly. I feel like we're approaching this incorrectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "it doesn't page the results properly"?

Comment: By the way if you only need the hash of the commits you could do `git log --pretty="%h"`

Answer (score 53):

I have encountered the exact same problem. I did manage to acquire all the commits for all branches within a repository (probably not that *efficient* due to the API).

### Approach to retrieve all commits for all branches in a repository

As you mentioned, first you gather all the branches:

```
# https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/branches
https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/branches
```

The key that you are missing is that APIv3 for getting commits operates using a reference commit (the parameter for the API call to list commits on a repository *sha*). So you need to make sure when you collect the branches that you also pick up their latest sha:

#### Trimmed result of branch API call for twitter/bootstrap

```
[
  {
    "commit": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/commits/8b19016c3bec59acb74d95a50efce70af2117382",
      "sha": "8b19016c3bec59acb74d95a50efce70af2117382"
    },
    "name": "gh-pages"
  },
  {
    "commit": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/commits/d335adf644b213a5ebc9cee3f37f781ad55194ef",
      "sha": "d335adf644b213a5ebc9cee3f37f781ad55194ef"
    },
    "name": "master"
  }
]
```

#### Working with last commit's sha

So as we see the two branches here have different sha, these are the latest commit sha on those branches. What you can do now is to iterate through each branch from their latest sha:

```
# With sha parameter of the branch's lastest sha
# https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits
https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/commits?per_page=100&sha=d335adf644b213a5ebc9cee3f37f781ad55194ef
```

So the above API call will list the last 100 commits of the *master* branch of *twitter/bootstrap*. Working with the API you have to specify the next commit's sha to get the next 100 commits. We can use the last commit's sha (which is *7a8d6b19767a92b1c4ea45d88d4eedc2b29bf1fa* using the current example) as input for the next API call:

```
# Next API call for commits (use the last commit's sha)
# https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits
https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/commits?per_page=100&sha=7a8d6b19767a92b1c4ea45d88d4eedc2b29bf1fa
```

This process is repeated until the last commit's sha is the same as the API's call sha parameter.

#### Next branch

That is it for one branch. Now you apply the same approach for the other branch (work from the latest sha).

---

There is a large issue with this approach... Since branches share some identical commits you will see the same commits over-and-over again as you move to another branch.

I can image that there is a much more efficient way to accomplish this, yet this worked for me.

Comment: What should I do if I'd like to get all commits from own private repo? Do you think authing  will get me necessary permissions and I'll get private repos too in the list of repos?

Comment: @hungryWolf I would suspect that the API calls using your auth token should do the trick -- provided you have adequate permissions on that token. Give it a shot, and let us know :)

Comment: yup auth token works and your answer was really helpful by the way

Comment: In your trimmed result, the `name` key with `branch` does not exist anymore for an api call to show commits.

Comment: you can also target a specific branch if you already know the name - `https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/branches/main` - where `main` is the branch name

Answer (score 39):

I asked this same question for GitHub support, and they answered me this:

> [GETing /repos/:owner/:repo/commits](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) should do the trick. You can pass the branch name in the `sha` parameter. For example, to get the first page of commits from the '3.0.0-wip' branch of [the twitter/bootstrap repository](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commits/3.0.0-wip), you would use the following curl request:
>
> ```
> curl https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/bootstrap/commits?sha=3.0.0-wip
> ```
>
> The docs also [describe how to use pagination to get the remaining commits](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) for this branch.
>
> As long as you are [making authenticated requests](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), you can make [up to 5,000 requests per hour](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting).

I used the rails github-api in my app as follows(using https://github.com/peter-murach/github gem):

```
github_connection = Github.new :client_id => 'your_id', :client_secret => 'your_secret', :oauth_token => 'your_oath_token'
branches_info = {}
all_branches = git_connection.repos.list_branches owner,repo_name
all_branches.body.each do |branch|
    branches_info["#{branch.name}".to_s] = "#{branch.commit.url}"
end
branches_info.keys.each do |branch|
    commits_list.push (git_connection.repos.commits.list owner,repo_name, start_date,      end_date, :sha => "branch_name")
end
```

Comment: I believe that "all_branches = git_connection.repos" should be "all_branches = github_connection."

Comment: this is not correct and returns all commits without filtering the branch name.

Answer (score 22):

## Using GraphQL API v4

You can use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to optimize commits download per branch. In the following method, I've managed to download in a single request 1900 commits (100 commits per branch in 19 different branches) which drastically reduces the number of requests (compared to using REST api).

### 1 - Get all branches

You will have to get all branches & go through pagination if you have more than 100 branches :

Query :

```graphql
query($owner:String!, $name:String!, $branchCursor: String!) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/",after: $branchCursor) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            ...on Commit {
              history(first:0){
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variables :

```
{
  "owner": "google",
  "name": "gson",
  "branchCursor": ""
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22owner%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22gson%22%2C%0A%20%20%22branchCursor%22%3A%20%22%22%0A%7D&query=query(%24owner%3AString!%2C%20%24name%3AString!%2C%20%24branchCursor%3A%20String!)%20%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%24owner%2C%20name%3A%20%24name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(first%3A%20100%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22%2Cafter%3A%20%24branchCursor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A0)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Note that `branchCursor` variable is used when you have more than 100 branches & features the value of `pageInfo.endCursor` in the previous request in that case.

### 2 - Split the branches array into array of 19 branches max

There is some limitation of the number of request per nodes that prevents us from making too much query per node. Here, some testing I've performed showed that we can't go over 19*100 commits in a single query.

Note that in case of repo which have < 19 branches, you don't need to bother about that

### 3 - Query commits by chunk of 100 for each branch

You can then create your query dynamically for getting the 100 next commits on all branches. An example with 2 branches :

```graphql
query ($owner: String!, $name: String!) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    branch0: ref(qualifiedName: "JsonArrayImplementsList") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 100) {
            ...CommitFragment
          }
        }
      }
    }
    branch1: ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 100) {
            ...CommitFragment
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection {
  totalCount
  nodes {
    oid
    message
    committedDate
    author {
      name
      email
    }
  }
  pageInfo {
    hasNextPage
    endCursor
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=query%20(%24owner%3A%20String!%2C%20%24name%3A%20String!)%20%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%24owner%2C%20name%3A%20%24name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20branch0%3A%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22JsonArrayImplementsList%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...CommitFragment%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20branch1%3A%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22master%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...CommitFragment%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20CommitFragment%20on%20CommitHistoryConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22owner%22%3A%20%22google%22%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22gson%22%0A%7D)

- The variables used are `owner` for the repo's owner & `name` for the name of the repo.
- A [fragment](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) in order to avoid duplication of commit history field definition.

You can see that `pageInfo.hasNextpage` & `pageInfo.endCursor` will be used to go through pagination for each branch. The pagination takes place in `history(first: 100)` with specification of the last cursor encountered. For instance the next request will have `history(first: 100, after: "6e2fcdcaf252c54a151ce6a4441280e4c54153ae 99")`. For each branch, we have to update the request with the last `endCursor` value to query for the 100 next commit.

When `pageInfo.hasNextPage` is `false`, there is no more page for this branch, so we won't include it in the next request.

When the last branch have `pageInfo.hasNextPage` to `false`, we have retrieved all commits

### Sample implementation

Here is a sample implementation in NodeJS using [github-graphql-client](https://github.com/imsky/github-graphql-client). The same method could be implemented in any other language. The following will also store commits in a file `commitsX.json` :

```javascript
var client = require('github-graphql-client');
var fs = require("fs");

const owner = "google";
const repo = "gson";
const accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

const branchQuery = `
query($owner:String!, $name:String!, $branchCursor: String!) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/",after: $branchCursor) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            ...on Commit {
              history(first:0){
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}`;

function buildCommitQuery(branches){
    var query = `
        query ($owner: String!, $name: String!) {
          repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {`;
    for (var key in branches) {
        if (branches.hasOwnProperty(key) && branches[key].hasNextPage) {
          query+=`
            ${key}: ref(qualifiedName: "${branches[key].name}") {
              target {
                ... on Commit {
                  history(first: 100, after: ${branches[key].cursor ? '"' + branches[key].cursor + '"': null}) {
                    ...CommitFragment
                  }
                }
              }
            }`;
        }
    }
    query+=`
          }
        }`;
    query+= commitFragment;
    return query;
}

const commitFragment = `
fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection {
  totalCount
  nodes {
    oid
    message
    committedDate
    author {
      name
      email
    }
  }
  pageInfo {
    hasNextPage
    endCursor
  }
}`;

function doRequest(query, variables) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    client({
        token: accessToken,
        query: query,
        variables: variables
    }, function (err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        resolve(res);
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

function buildBranchObject(branch){
    var refs = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
        console.log("branch " + branch[i].node.name);
        refs["branch" + i] = {
            name: branch[i].node.name,
            totalCount: branch[i].node.target.history.totalCount,
            cursor: null,
            hasNextPage : true,
            commits: []
        };
    }
    return refs;
}

async function requestGraphql() {
    var iterateBranch = true;
    var branches = [];
    var cursor = "";

    // get all branches
    while (iterateBranch) {
        let res = await doRequest(branchQuery,{
          "owner": owner,
          "name": repo,
          "branchCursor": cursor
        });
        iterateBranch = res.data.repository.refs.pageInfo.hasNextPage;
        cursor = res.data.repository.refs.pageInfo.endCursor;
        branches = branches.concat(res.data.repository.refs.edges);
    }

    //split the branch array into smaller array of 19 items
    var refChunk = [], size = 19;

    while (branches.length > 0){
        refChunk.push(branches.splice(0, size));
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < refChunk.length; j++) {

        //1) store branches in a format that makes it easy to concat commit when receiving the query result
        var refs = buildBranchObject(refChunk[j]);

        //2) query commits while there are some pages existing. Note that branches that don't have pages are not 
        //added in subsequent request. When there are no more page, the loop exit
        var hasNextPage = true;
        var count = 0;

        while (hasNextPage) {
            var commitQuery = buildCommitQuery(refs);
            console.log("request : " + count);
            let commitResult = await doRequest(commitQuery, {
              "owner": owner,
              "name": repo
            });
            hasNextPage = false;
            for (var key in refs) {
                if (refs.hasOwnProperty(key) && commitResult.data.repository[key]) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    let history = commitResult.data.repository[key].target.history;
                    refs[key].commits = refs[key].commits.concat(history.nodes);
                    refs[key].cursor = (history.pageInfo.hasNextPage) ? history.pageInfo.endCursor : '';
                    refs[key].hasNextPage = history.pageInfo.hasNextPage;
                    console.log(key + " : " + refs[key].commits.length + "/" + refs[key].totalCount + " : " + refs[key].hasNextPage + " : " + refs[key].cursor + " : " + refs[key].name);
                    if (refs[key].hasNextPage){
                        hasNextPage = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
            console.log("------------------------------------");
        }
        for (var key in refs) {
            if (refs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(refs[key].totalCount + " : " + refs[key].commits.length + " : " + refs[key].name);
            }
        }

        //3) write commits chunk (up to 19 branches) in a single json file
        fs.writeFile("commits" + j + ".json", JSON.stringify(refs, null, 4), "utf8", function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("done");
        });
    }
}

requestGraphql();
```

This also work with repo with a lot of branches, for instances [this one](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_manifest) which has more than 700 branches

### Rate Limit

Note that while it is true that with GraphQL you can perform a reduced number of requests, it won't necessarily improve your rate limit as the rate limit is based on points & not a limited number of requests : check [GraphQL API rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/#rate-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS Implementation without Access Token (Unauthorised Usage)

```js
const base_url = 'https://api.github.com';

    function httpGet(theUrl, return_headers) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        if (return_headers) {
            return xmlHttp
        }
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    function get_all_commits_count(owner, repo, sha) {
        let first_commit = get_first_commit(owner, repo);
        let compare_url = base_url + '/repos/' + owner + '/' + repo + '/compare/' + first_commit + '...' + sha;
        let commit_req = httpGet(compare_url);
        let commit_count = JSON.parse(commit_req)['total_commits'] + 1;
        console.log('Commit Count: ', commit_count);
        return commit_count
    }

    function get_first_commit(owner, repo) {
        let url = base_url + '/repos/' + owner + '/' + repo + '/commits';
        let req = httpGet(url, true);
        let first_commit_hash = '';
        if (req.getResponseHeader('Link')) {
            let page_url = req.getResponseHeader('Link').split(',')[1].split(';')[0].split('<')[1].split('>')[0];
            let req_last_commit = httpGet(page_url);
            let first_commit = JSON.parse(req_last_commit);
            first_commit_hash = first_commit[first_commit.length - 1]['sha']
        } else {
            let first_commit = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            first_commit_hash = first_commit[first_commit.length - 1]['sha'];
        }
        return first_commit_hash;
    }

    let owner = 'getredash';
    let repo = 'redash';
    let sha = 'master';
    get_all_commits_count(owner, repo, sha);
```

Credits - https://gist.github.com/yershalom/a7c08f9441d1aadb13777bce4c7cdc3b

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fetch_user_github_commits(token, project_id, since, until, author):
    """
    Fetch user project commits.

    :param token: gho_ABCH1231231ASDKJH123123123
    :param projected: user/repository
    :param since: 2024-03-13T00:00:00Z
    :param until: 2024-03-13T23:59:59Z
    :param author: github user node_id
    :return:
    """
    url = f'{settings.GITHUB_API_URL}graphql'
    user, repo = project_id.split("/")

    query_template = """
query($owner: String!, $name: String!, $since: GitTimestamp!, $until: GitTimestamp!, $cursor: String, $author: ID) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 100, after: $cursor) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        name
        target {
          ... on Commit {
            history(first: 100, since: $since, until: $until, author: { id: $author }) {
              nodes {
                sha: oid
                message
                author {
                  name
                  email
                  date
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

    all_commits = []
    cursor = None

    while True:
        variables = {
            "owner": user,
            "name": repo,
            "since": since,
            "until": until,
            "author": author,
            "cursor": cursor
        }

        response = requests.post(
            url,
            headers={
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            json={"query": query_template, "variables": variables}
        )

        if response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED:
            raise NotAuthenticated("Invalid Github OAuth Token")

        if response.status_code != status.HTTP_200_OK:
            logger.error(response.json())
            break

        data = response.json().get("data")
        if not data:
            break

        refs = data["repository"]["refs"]
        for node in refs["nodes"]:
            commits = node["target"]["history"]["nodes"]
            all_commits.extend(commits)

        if not refs["pageInfo"]["hasNextPage"]:
            break

        cursor = refs["pageInfo"]["endCursor"]

    return all_commits
```