# github api: How to efficiently find the number of commits for a repository?

Tags: github, github-api

I want to find the number of commits done to specific github projects, and within them to specific files. I checked the [github api docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) but only found an API for actually returning all commits. This would be very inefficient since I have to do multiple api calls for paging thru all commits.

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: @drorw Hello, may you please tell me how you integrated the access token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update May 2013: see "[File CRUD and repository statistics now available in the API](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api)"

You now can [Get the last year of commit activity data](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-last-year-of-commit-activity-data)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/commit_activity
```

> Returns the last year of commit activity grouped by week. The days array is a group of commits per day, starting on Sunday.

Not *completely* what you are looking for, but closer.

---

Original answer (April 2010)

No, the current API doesn't support a '`log --all`' for listing all commmits from all branches.

The only alternative is presented in "[Github API: Retrieve all commits for all branches for a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179828/github-api-retrieve-all-commits-for-all-branches-for-a-repo)", and list through all pages of all commits, *branch after branch*.

This seems so cumbersome than another alternative would actually to *clone* the Github repo and [apply git commands on that local clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count)!
(mainly [`git shortlog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog))

---

Note: you can also checkout that [python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682970/6309) created by [Arcsector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6284028/arcsector).

Comment: @drorw If you have specific suggestions or feature requests regarding the API, you should e-mail GitHub support and let them know: https://github.com/contact

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get more than a year?

Comment: @Pachonk No: I suppose the github support would though.

Answer (score 5):

With [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you can get total commit count per branch with [`totalCount`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/commithistoryconnection/#commithistoryconnection) for each branch:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "google", name: "gson") {
    name
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              id
              history(first: 0) {
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Test it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22google%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22gson%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20refs(first%3A%20100%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: If you want the number of commits from only the default branch, you can use a similar approach, but using the `defaultBranchRef` property instead of `refs`.

Answer (score 1):

0penBrain found a clever way to obtain this information and detailed it in the following Gist : https://gist.github.com/0penBrain/7be59a48aba778c955d992aa69e524c5

Here's the relevant snippet with `curl` :

```
curl -I -k "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?per_page=1" | sed -n '/^[Ll]ink:/ s/.*"next".*page=\([0-9]*\).*"last".*/\1/p'
```

The trick is to enable a 1 commit per page pagination, as can be seen in the query-string.
Then the focus must shift from the response JSON body to the HTTP headers where the following entry can be found :

```
link: <https://api.github.com/repositories/27193779/commits?per_page=1&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/27193779/commits?per_page=1&page=37949>; rel="last"
```

The `sed` expression is then in charge of extracting the `37949` number (in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS Implementation

```js
const base_url = 'https://api.github.com';

    function httpGet(theUrl, return_headers) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        if (return_headers) {
            return xmlHttp
        }
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    function get_all_commits_count(owner, repo, sha) {
        let first_commit = get_first_commit(owner, repo);
        let compare_url = base_url + '/repos/' + owner + '/' + repo + '/compare/' + first_commit + '...' + sha;
        let commit_req = httpGet(compare_url);
        let commit_count = JSON.parse(commit_req)['total_commits'] + 1;
        console.log('Commit Count: ', commit_count);
        return commit_count
    }

    function get_first_commit(owner, repo) {
        let url = base_url + '/repos/' + owner + '/' + repo + '/commits';
        let req = httpGet(url, true);
        let first_commit_hash = '';
        if (req.getResponseHeader('Link')) {
            let page_url = req.getResponseHeader('Link').split(',')[1].split(';')[0].split('<')[1].split('>')[0];
            let req_last_commit = httpGet(page_url);
            let first_commit = JSON.parse(req_last_commit);
            first_commit_hash = first_commit[first_commit.length - 1]['sha']
        } else {
            let first_commit = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            first_commit_hash = first_commit[first_commit.length - 1]['sha'];
        }
        return first_commit_hash;
    }

    let owner = 'getredash';
    let repo = 'redash';
    let sha = 'master';
    get_all_commits_count(owner, repo, sha);
```

Credits - https://gist.github.com/yershalom/a7c08f9441d1aadb13777bce4c7cdc3b