# GitHub API: finding number of stars,commits and releases

Tags: android, json, github-api

I'm making an Android app that uses the GitHub API. My goal is to make a list of repositories for a github user.

I've tried using `GET /users/:username/repos`, but it doesn't return all of the info I need. How can I get all of the repository data for each repository belonging to the user?

Answer (score 5):

By making requests to `/users/:username/repos` you get the list of repositories for the specified user but they contain the important fields. This is called [*Summary Representation*](https://developer.github.com/v3/#summary-representations).

#### Stars

The list of repositories contain repository objects containing the `stargazers_count` which is the number of stars.

#### Commits count

Get the contributors and sum the commit counts, like [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938964/1420197).

#### Releases

Use the [`/repos/:owner/:repo/releases`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) endpoint:

> `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases?per_page=1`
>
> ```
> Status: 200 OK
> Link: <https://api.github.com/resource?page=2>; rel="next",
>       <https://api.github.com/resource?page=5>; rel="last"
> X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
> X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
> ```

You can use `rel="last"` from the the `Link` header to get the releases count (in this example `5`).

By using `per_page=1` we limit the number of objects per page to one, so we can just get then the number of pages and know it's the same with the number of releases.