# Count number of commits in through GitHub API command

Tags: git, github-api, git-commit

I am pulling the commit information using GitHub Enterprise API. Sample API command is

```
"curl -i -H 'Authorization: token XXXXX' https://git.xxxx.com/api/v3/repos/DataPortal/search-service/commits?page=1&per_page=100 "
```

Is there any way to get the total commit count in a command? Right now I am trying to iterate per page  but for repos with huge number of commits, git is resetting the connection.

Comment: The accepted answer on the following link might help.
[How to use github v3 api to get commit count for a repo.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931139/how-to-use-github-v3-api-to-get-commit-count-for-a-repo)

Comment: Thanks! it seems like a viable solution. Will try it out !