# How can I get a commit count through github-api?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I want to get a year's commit count for the user.
I checked the github-api v3 reference.
but, Only the repertory commit count could be known.
How can I know the number of commit to all repertories in a year for a user?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/27931139/2614364

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use the call `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits` with parameter `since` and `until` which are used for the start date and end date in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` format. Also, we can pass the `author` parameter for getting the commits done by that particular author.