# Get a user's total commit count for all repos

Tags: javascript, html, github

I want to have a stat on my website with the number of total commits I have on Github, across all of my repositories, not just for a year. Is there a way to do that, ideally with Javascript?

I've tried looking through the GitHub API pages, but I can only find the total commit count for a single repository.

Comment: So loop over all the repos and add up the commit counts.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610670/9038475), which is based on [this](https://gist.github.com/0penBrain/7be59a48aba778c955d992aa69e524c5)?