# Github API access via java client

Tags: github-api

I want to write a simple java program or client which can get count of  all the commits done by users.

How can I write it? Ie, How to use Github APi's in our code so I get the right result?
There are some API's present, but can somebody give example as to how to use it in java client?

Comment: I  was going through githib but was unable to get any java apis will try org.eclipse.egit.github.core (it has a Contributor object) ..

Answer (score 1):

I [explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919708/6309) that counting *all* the commits of a repo isn't available in GitHub API for commits.

However, the [GitHub API for Statistics](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) proposes a **[contributor](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#contributors)** call with a `total` field which can be interesting.

```
total
```

> The Total number of commits authored by the contributor.

From the [GitHub libraries pages](https://developer.github.com/libraries/), you can call this API in Java with:

- [`org.eclipse.egit.github.core`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) (it has a [`Contributor` object](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/6e30f1041361334024f05ae62d74ec222565ab13/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/Contributor.java))
- or [**github-api.kohsuke.org**](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/)