# Is it possible to get remote git log to gather full commit history of a repository?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm finding something like this `git log --remote --full-depth <url>` or some variations, or approaches from bash / python to get full history of the repository without `git clone`

I want to get full history of the repository's commits to calculate some metrics using this data.

The question a partly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon), but I want to get full history.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to clone/fetch the repo, then you would need to use the [GitHub API for commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) in order to get those same commits without cloning. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16782303/6309).

But you also have the [GitHub Statistic API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) to directly get some stats on those commits, without having to fetch them first.