# github email notification when changes occurs on public repo?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Does this exist? There are a couple of public repos that I have read access to that I want to be notified of when a commit is made. I cant seem to find this anywhere, does this exist? Or how can I get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this out :

[Github API: Retrieve all commits for all branches for a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179828/github-api-retrieve-all-commits-for-all-branches-for-a-repo)

And the github API doc.

For a notification, you can check your lastID and compare if it changes. It's what I did for twitter