# Get the user who created a branch with GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

### Background

- I am using GitHub Enterprise.
  I want to check unused branches in my repository, and ask owners of these unused branches to clean-up.
- You can see "Your branches" (branches created by current user) on “Branches” page in GitHub. So I think GitHub might have information for who created a branch.
- On the other hand, the result of GitHub REST API (https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference) does not contain the creator of the specified branch.

### Question

Is there’s any way to get the user who created a branch with GitHub API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real "ownership" associated to a branch with Git/GitHub.
As mentioned in [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/), "Your branches" reference in a repository the branches you have push access to, not necessarily the ones you have "created".

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/branches/branches-overview-atom.png]

The best you can do is, if you have access to a local clone, a simple `git fetch`, followed by:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate) %09 %(refname:short) %09 %(authorname)" --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes/origin
```

That will list the remote branches from the most recent updated one to the oldest, with the author of the *last* commit on each branch.

But if you have to use GitHub API, then you would need to:

- [list the remote branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-branches),
- then for each one [get the commit mentioned with the branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit)

You can then contact the committer of that most recent commit.

Comment: I took a brief look at my repository and I found that, in the most branches, the user who added the first commit to an branch was the creator of that branch. How can I list the author of the first commit on each branch, rather than the last one?

Comment: @satob if you need to contact someone, it is best to contact the one who most recently updated the branch. But if you must: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32870852/6309 (CLI solution) or graphql solution (if you don't have a local clone): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47523826/6309