# Using GIT Api can I find the branch name from a commit id

Tags: git, github

I have a sha lets say "abcdefghijk" . I want to find the exact branch name from where the commit came from . I tried looking for other answers but most of them have some iterations or use command line , the restriction I have is **I need to use only GIT API (Rest)** to retrieve the branch name .

I tried looking for search API but it gives me commit details and the commit details doesn't contain branch name . Even if I get the pull request from where the commit is coming from would also be helpful . So using GIT API I want to check either the branch name or the pull request from where the commit is coming from .

Any help here is appreciated .

Reason : Why I want to know branch name

So let's say the manifest created for deployment is created from master branch . So let's say there are 2 PR's from a feature branch which was merged to the master branch .

```
master_branch
     --PR1 (From Feature Branch which has 1 commit)
     --PR2 (From Feature Branch which has 2 commit)
```

Now those commits will appear in Master Branch .

Now Feature Branch in PR1 had 1 commit made 3 days before deployment . Feature branch in PR 2 has 1 commit made 3 days before and second commit made 11 days before deployment .

I want to know from which branch those commits came from . Reason is I want to know which branch commits took max time to make it to the master branch (ie: Point out the fault branch which took max time to make it to master after first commit ) .

Comment: There is no Git REST API, and commits aren't "from" branches, let alone unique ones. Are you trying to tie commits to some external administrative record, or what?

Comment: Updated my question for  reason why I want to know the branch names .

Comment: There is a Git-**HUB** REST API. It is not a Git REST API. There is a Git API of sorts, but it uses the command line, and is not REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now those commits will appear in Master Branch .

They will if those PRs have been merged in a [fast-forward manner](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges).
If they are merged in a non-fast-forward, resulting in a merge commit (F below), then a [`git branch --contain <sha1>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309) would still return "`feature`" (unless the [PR branch has been deleted](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/deleting-and-restoring-branches-in-a-pull-request))

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/standard-merge-commit-diagram.png]

The problem is: The [Branch GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#branches) does not include a filter for a specific commit, so you might need to [get all commits for PR branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9179828/6309) (possibly [using GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47523826/6309)) in order to get that information from API only.

Comment: I see ,so there is no direct way via GIT API to get branch name via commit id .

Comment: @arpitjoshi No, not that I know of.