# Is there a way to use go-github client to get all or some of the remote branches that contains a git sha?

Tags: go, go-github

Writing a go GitHub client that can get branch names based on a git sha.

Answer (score 0):

[Last time I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68158985/6309), there was no easy way to list remote GitHub branches which includes a specific commit, even [using GraphQL](https://github.community/t/graphql-given-a-commits-sha1-from-git-find-the-branches-it-belongs-to/14620)

So that would not be possible with [`go-github`](https://github.com/google/go-github) either.